# Coinbase API: buy and sell prices are not as accurate as the spot price

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I need help figuring out if I'm doing something wrong with the API calls.

In python using the library provided by coinbase I run this code:

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

client = Client(coinbase_API_key, coinbase_API_secret)

print(client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = 'SHIB-EUR'))
print(client.get_sell_price(currency_pair = 'SHIB-EUR'))
print(client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'SHIB-EUR'))
```

And the console gives me these values:

```
{
  "amount": "0.00",
  "base": "SHIB",
  "currency": "EUR"
}
{
  "amount": "0.00",
  "base": "SHIB",
  "currency": "EUR"
}
{
  "amount": "0.000043788348",
  "base": "SHIB",
  "currency": "EUR"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or does the API not have accurate prices?

Comment: any reason you're not using the cb pro api for this?

Comment: @Travis because I didn't know .. sorry. Do you have any sample code or a link for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_postorders

Comment: @Travis thank you but I wan't to check the price of a crypto, not buy it or sell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to use the Ticker if you want the price:

https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/SHIB-EUR/ticker

to answer your question:

> Am I doing something wrong or does the API not have accurate prices?

I think coinbase had some issues listing shib because of the 9 decimals so it's possible all the issues including the coinbase.com api hasn't solved them.  OR they're not overly interested on showing the accurate price on .com because they like to overcharge with slipage anyway.